# Why does EF Reverse Code First Tool generate a composite key?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

EF Reverse Code First Tool is generating a composite key

```cs
public vw_ResourcesMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.Refno, t.Obsolete }); // Why???

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Refno)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.LocnID)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(2);

        this.Property(t => t.Created_by)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("vw_Resources");
        this.Property(t => t.Refno).HasColumnName("Refno");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.Head).HasColumnName("Head");
        this.Property(t => t.LocnID).HasColumnName("LocnID");
        this.Property(t => t.Obsolete).HasColumnName("Obsolete");
        this.Property(t => t.Created_by).HasColumnName("Created_by");
        this.Property(t => t.Version).HasColumnName("Version");
        this.Property(t => t.Rank).HasColumnName("Rank");
    }
}
```

I had to change the Primary Key declaration to `this.HasKey(t => t.Refno)` to map the relationship otherwise I would get the exception below.

> The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

Maybe it's a bug -- IDK

All is working, but would like to increase understanding and knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it reverse engineered mapping of database view? Are other columns nullable?

Comment: I had the similar problem because i was changing the database constantly and using reverse engineering after changes to map the DB again properly so one time i forgot to make changes to the database and it resulted in the same error as yours. The problem was that i removed IDENTITY from one column and added to another that shouldn't be IDENTITY.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Yes it is mapping this was an update to the tool. The columns were nullable. Primary in particular needed to be non-null to satisfy the relationship (if I remember correctly).

Comment: @plurbyI have been doing the same `changing db and using reverse engineering to map` strange thing is that it did it for all the views, so I don't believe that was the case with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database view doesn't have primary key so EF tries to infer the key by using all non nullable columns which don't use binary data types.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Thanks! BTY - I really appreciate all your work on SO and your blog -- been very helpful!